K6 custom report - grab threshold failures output
I'm trying to write custom reporting and grab all messages from K6 run. The issue I see that when I'm saving summaryData into txt file I don't see logs on threshold failures like this:

ERRO[0088] thresholds on metrics 'PUT_api_buyer_sa_buyer_buyerID_contact_contact, PUT_api_buyer_sa_buyer_buyerID_contact_contactID' have been crossed

I have code:
export function handleSummary(summaryData) {
  const data = summaryData;
  return {
    stdout: textSummary(data, { indent: " ", enableColors: true }) ,
    [`report_summary_${__ENV.TIMESTAMP}.txt`]: textSummary(data, {
      indent: " ",
      enableColors: false,
    }),
  };
  }

But looks like it does not redirect console.log() into txt file
Is there a way to actually grab all logs that I see in console from K6 run and redirect them to txt file? But I'm definitely can not see those last lines in *.txt output file and also console.log() as well
Thank you all for help here!


You don't have access to (past) console output in the handleSummary function. If you want to write the console output to a file, redirect the k6 output to a file:

k6 run ./your_script.js > logs.txt
or k6 run ./your_script.js | tee logs.txt to see them in the terminal and write to the file at the same time

Alternatively, if you only want to know which thresholds have been crossed, you can extract this information from the first argument passed to the handleSummary function:
export function handleSummary(summaryData) {
  const failedMetrics = [];
  for (const [metric, value] of Object.entries(summaryData.metrics)) {
    const thresholds = value.thresholds;
    if (Object.values(thresholds).some(t => !t.ok)) {
      failedMetrics.push(metric);
    }
  }

  return {
    `failed_thresholds.txt`: JSON.stringify(failedMetrics),
  };
}

The summaryData.metrics object looks like this example from the docs:
{
  "http_req_duration": {
    "type": "trend",
    "contains": "time",
    "values": {
      "avg": 268.31137452500013,
      "max": 846.198634,
      "p(99.99)": 846.1969478817999
    },
    "thresholds": {
      "p(95)<500": {
        "ok": false
      }
    }
  }
}

Of course you are free to structure your output data any way you want: print the actual failed threshold (e.g. P(99) < 500 was crossed), group your metrics, write the metric values for the failed thresholds.
